# Magento : Related Product issue

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view, related-products

I have added related product to one simple product it's all are display in product detail page but it's not display with checkbox  for select so that i am not able to add that product to cart. 
According to me following code has issue to display checkbox.

```
   <?php if(!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable()): ?>
        <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
           <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox related-checkbox" id="related-checkbox<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" name="related_products[]" value="<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" />
        <?php endif; ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
```

This code is already in this path:

> /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list/related.phtml line no 37

if you have any idea about this please share it with me.

Thanks

Comment: do your related product has so some required options ?

Comment: No, there is not any required option. are you talking about required field ?

Comment: ok so related product are also simple products . Correct ?

Comment: Yes, Related product is also simple product and in which product i have added this is also simple product.

Comment: checkboxes are showing in my case with above scenario. can you please check which condition is making false in above code ?

Comment: Yes, if i remove not sign (!) from this <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?> it will display checkbox but after select all checkbox clicking on add to cart then selected product not adding to cart.

Comment: Do you have setup custom options for related product ?

Comment: No, i have set up for one product and for other product i have set custom options.

Comment: probably you have have setup required custom option for your related products, thats why it checks the getRequiredoption Condition and that makes it true and  not(!) sign makes it false.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84178/discussion-between-sarfaraj-and-shashank).